# Eclipse CDT and MinGW Compiler Build and Clean Errors

Tags: eclipse, mingw-w64, tdm-mingw

I'm getting started with Eclipse CDT (Luna) and MinGW (TDM64-gcc-4.9.2-3 and or MinGW64) compiler on Windows(x64). Everything seems ok but there are some console outputs which makes me worry.

for example when i clean my project, following errors occur:

Cannot run program "rm": Launching failed

**Error: Program "rm" not found in PATH**

Although i can see that project gets clean??? **I've found that rm.exe is not really in the path.**

Also when i try to build my programs, everything works fine, but following info shows up:

**Info: Internal Builder is used for build**

g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o version-test.o "..\version-test.cpp"

g++ -o Working.exe version-test.o

output of program "version-test" is exactly as it should be (Same as Lynda Tutorials), it generates following output(c++11 features are working):

GCC version: 4.9.2
Version string: 4.9.2
one
two
three

So here is my question. Why everything is working without any real errors, But i am seeing this Info and Error???

Are this things important???